# Multiple Monitors w/ Different Video Cards

Tags: windows-7, drivers, multiple-monitors, graphics-card

I currently have an NVIDIA GeForce 8600 running 2 monitors. I'd like to run a 3rd off the Intel G965 onboard graphics, but Windows 7 won't run both drivers at once.

Any advice?

Answer (score 1):

Installing a PCIe video card automatically disables the integrated PCIe graphics. You can't use both at once.

Comment: Really? That's a shame.

Comment: That's the case for most, but not all systems.  For example, if the onboard is an ATI and you install an ATI, and they both support the standard that lets them talk to each other ("cross fire" or something), then you can use them together.  But typically, this is indeed the case.